Django Development Server Success Message on my EC2 Instance's public ipv4 address and django' default port
I have launched and EC2 Instance with Windows AMI and a security group that has 4 inbound rules. 1. Allow http traffic from all IP addresses 2. Allow https traffic from all IP addresses 3. Custom TCP with port 8000 and RDP to connect to the instance using RDP client. I have connected to the ec2 instance using RDP client and have added an inbound rule for port 8000 on windows firewall. I downloaded python and Django and created a project on the ec2 desktop
When I run the development server on the localhost in this case the ec2 instance it is showing the success message. When I want now to run the development server using my ec2 instance's public ipv4 address and port 8000 it is saying this site cannot be reached. Can you help me guys so that when I open my public ipv4 address I can see the success message

add the external IP to the allowed_hosts entry to settings.py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost','127.0.0.1','nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn',]

